# OpenFeint and Phonegap view problem

Tags: iphone, uiview, cordova, openfeint

I am testing my app on a ipod Touch 4g iOS 4.2. Please note I tested the app on an iphone 2G with iOS 4.2 and this was not an issue.

The initial OpenFeint approval view launches, but the Phonegap view immediately lauches soon after so that the user has no time to enable/ignore Openfeint.

Even worse, the top of the phonegap view is clipped off and you can see the the Openfeint approval screen sitting there behind it.

I can use the app and openfeint works in offline mode registering high score and achievements.

My impression of Openfeint is that its view should go straigh to the top whenever it launches but for some reason it's not happening here.

I'm trying a few UIView methods and property changes but no luck so far.

Anyone come across this or understand how either of the view systems work.

I'll continue my debugging and report back but let me know if anyone out there has a good idea and/or insight.

Thanks

Nigel

Answer (score 0):

I think worked this out. May be a few bugs. Require more thorough testing. Will report back.

Basically I disabled the default Openfeint Approval process and set up my own one using the OpenfeintDelegate.h

- (BOOL)showCustomOpenFeintApprovalScreen
  {

  SCNetworkReachabilityRef reach = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorSystemDefault, "google.com");
  SCNetworkConnectionFlags flags;
  SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reach, &flags);

  if(kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable & flags) {
  // The internet can be accessed using the current connection.

  ```
      UIAlertView *alert = [ [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"OpenFeint Approval" 
                                      message:@"Do you want the awesome leaderboard, acheivement and challenge features offered by OpenFeint? (Remember this data will be stored on OpenFeint servers)" 
                                      delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"No thanks" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil 
                    ]; 

  [alert show];
  [alert release];
  ```

  }

  return YES;
  }